# Is it true that $\left|\frac{\zeta(0.5+it) }{\zeta(0.5-it)}\right|\leq 1 $, for $t\in \mathbb{R} $?

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta, upper-lower-bounds

I'm interested one Bounds values of Riemann zeta function on critical line , really i have got this from some computation I did in wolfram alpha for some  values of $t$  and according to the studying number of solution of : $\zeta(0.5+it )= z$ , for every real $t$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$  this Bounds :

$$\left|\frac{\zeta(0.5+it) }{\zeta(0.5-it)}\right|\leq 1 $$

Now if we assume RH Holds the inequality is become an equality to $1$ by passage of limit  and it is  true if $(t=0)$ , But what about $t \neq 0$  ?

Comment: Isn't it always equal to $1$?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown is right. No matter if the RH holds, it is always equal to 1

Comment: If it was not equal to one, then the inequality could not hold. Just replace $t$ by $-t$.

Comment: $\zeta(1/2+it)$ and $\zeta(1/2-it)$ have the same modulus since they are complex conjugates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any meromorphic function $f$ real-valued on the real line has the property that $f(\overline s)=\overline{f(s)}$, so the absolute values are identical. It's nothing special to zeta.